# IRB.start not starting

Tags: ruby, rubygems, irb

I have some code that runs IRB.start (from inside a gem)

However, I get this error in magic-file.rb "No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - console"

```
/Users/you/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/magic-file.rb:7:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - console (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/you/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/magic-file.rb:7:in `open'
    from /Users/you/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/magic-file.rb:7:in `open'
    from /Users/you/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/input-method.rb:100:in `initialize'
    from /Users/you/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/context.rb:84:in `new'
    from /Users/you/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/context.rb:84:in `initialize'
    from /Users/you/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:426:in `new'
    from /Users/you/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:426:in `initialize'
    from /Users/you/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:381:in `new'
    from /Users/you/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:381:in `start'
    from /Users/you/projects/mygem/lib/mygem/commands.rb:20:in `console'
```

Comment: I just experienced the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out!  By looking through the code:

- https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/irb.rb
- https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/trunk/lib/irb/

I was able to determine that IRB checks ARGV so that you can pass IRB args on the commandline to whatever script you're invoking IRB.start in.

But since I was trying to create a rake task to start a console with my libraries preloaded for convenience, my command line was:

```
rake console
```

And IRB was trying to load the file 'console', because it assumes the first arg without a hyphen is a script to run.  Kind of annoying.  (IRB.start should take args as a method arg to avoid this tight coupling.)

I managed to fix it by adding this before my IRB.start:

```
ARGV.clear
```

**UPDATE:** Since it was requested, here's exactly where ARGV is used:

- https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/irb/init.rb#L124

Comment: What line in https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/irb.rb does it check argv?